# As dQ=nCdT, why not dQ is zero in isothermal process?

Tags: thermodynamics

Explain in detail about the terms used in first law.

Comment: Related: [If a gas absorbs heat, then how can its temperature remain constant?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/43006/7951)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/315381/specific-heat-in-isothermal-and-adiabatic-process-for-gas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation only gives the correct relationship between the heat and the temperature change when there is no work done.  Otherwise, it gives the wrong answer (as you have noted).  So, in thermodynamics, where the system can also exchange work with its surroundings, we no longer define heat capacity in terms of the amount of heat transfer.  Instead, $C_v$ is now defined in terms of the internal energy U, such that $dU=nC_vdT$, and $C_p$ is now defined in terms of the enthalpy H, such that $dH=nC_pdT$.  More precisely, $C_v$ is the partial derivative of internal energy per mole with respect to temperature at constant molar volume, and $C_p$ is the partial derivative of the enthalpy per mole with respect to temperature at constant pressure.  Heat, which is a function of path (and not state) is no longer used to define heat capacity.